# python-social-auth and facebook login: what is the whitelist redirect url to include in fb configuration?

Tags: python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I was getting this facebook login error:

> URL Blocked 
>   This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

Facebook login requires whitelisting of the call-back url.

what is the call back url for django-social-auth or  python-social-auth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include a url to your website that is the absolute url version of this relative url:
/complete/facebook/

how to find this out?
use Chrome browser dev tools, enable preserve log, try to login to your app.

This question / answer is for django-social-auth but likely applies to python-social-auth too.